# How to change a LibreOffice Impress presentation from 4:3 to 16:9 ratio?

Tags: libreoffice

This is possible in Microsoft Office via File->Page Setup, but in Impress no such option is available?.

Is it possible to at all? If so how?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For LibreOffice up to version 4.x:

1. Click **Format**
2. Select **Page**
3. Click **Screen**
4. Scroll through the various screen sizes until you see one that matches your criteria.

Comment: I don't have screen resolutions in that dialog. What version do you have?

Answer (score 45):

For Version LibreOffice 5.1.2.2.
- Select menu option "Slide"
- Select "page/slides properties.."
- Select folder "Page" and "Paper format" options.

Comment: Beware that this can take some time and give the appearance of hanging LibreOffice.

Comment: I have version 5.2.4.2 and the menu option is *"Slide"* -> *"Slide Properties..."*  . One might expect this to apply to only the current slide, but no. It changes dimensions for the whole slide deck.

Comment: @HarryWood: That opens the same "Page" window popup as the proposed approach.

Answer (score 12):

Annoying but true. Changed in LibreOffice > 5.0. Go to:

-> slide -> Page Slide Properties

and then adjust. Just took me half an hour to find this menu item. It sucks because official documentation is not updated and finding specific items in menus and submenus can take you a long time.

Comment: that's where the unity search feature comes in handy - press Alt and start typing what you're looking for

Comment: this will help me spare some time. Thx for the hint!  does this work for any menu command in any program?

Comment: yes it works in any program with menus

Answer (score 4):

In Impress Version: 4.2.7.2

Make like so:
[image: aspect]

Answer (score 1):

For version LibreOffice 3.5.4.2

Format -> Page

must be put:

formar: user

width: 16 cm

high: 9 cm

impress takes the aspect ratio 16:9!

Comment: sorry for not being specific, I already edited.