# How to change a LibreOffice Impress presentation from 4:3 to 16:9 ratio for version 6?

Tags: libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice Impress version 6.0.7.3. I can't find the setting for changing the aspect ratio.

---

I did find [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139053/how-to-change-a-libreoffice-impress-presentation-from-43-to-169-ratio) but the answers only address previous versions. It appears it was already changed before:

- below version 5: Format > Page > Screen
- version 5: Slide > Page/slides properties ... > Page > Paper format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find that dialog box under Slide-->Properties-->Page.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm for  6.0.7.3: Slide -> Properties -> Page contains "Format" which contains "Screen 16:9" etc. I must have overlooked that.